# Rank over $\mathbb F_p$ compared to rank over $\mathbb R$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, finite-fields, matrix-rank

I'm looking at the rank of certain square matrices given some constraints on the entries. The matrix entries are in $\mathbb Z_p$, and I want to minimize the rank under some conditions.

Suppose I know the family of matrices that satisfy my conditions and achieve minimal rank when I compute it over $\mathbb R$. Now I want to do the same over $\mathbb F_p$. Since $\mathbb F_p\not\subseteq\mathbb R$, there is no nice relation that I'm aware of that can directly evaluate the rank exactly. But can I at least say something like:

> If $M$ achieves minimal rank over $\mathbb R$, there there is no matrix $M'$ such that $rank_{\mathbb F_p}(M')<rank_{\mathbb F_p}(M)$.

Call the set of matrices in $\mathbb M_n(\mathbb Z_p)$ with rank $C$ over a field $K$, $S_\min(K,n:C)$. What can we say about $|S(\mathbb F_p,n:C)|$ compared to $|S(\mathbb R,n:C)|$? Any pointers towards special cases, or results on well known families of matrices are also helpful!

Comment: First, it would be more sensible to consider $\mathbb F_p$ vs $\mathbb Q$ (or if you know a little more algebra, the ring $\mathbb Z$) as completeness of the reals is a distraction here.  Second either evaluate maximally sized principal submatrix with non-zero determinant or use Smith Normal Form to show rank is non-decreasing when going from $\mathbb F_p$ to $\mathbb Q$.  The "family of matrices" is too vague to say much more.

Comment: @user8675309 I can't really change the setup I've been handed but maybe I can work with Q. Also the second thing is not what I asked. What I'm asking is the following: is it true that the matrix that achieves the minimal rank over an infinite field also achieves the minimal rank over a finite field? Or is there a different matrix with possibly larger rank over $\mathbb R$ that may achieve even lower rank over the finite field? This doesn't violate the monotonicity of rank as you pointed out. Or do you mean this may vary with the family?

Comment: There's a lot of missing background/context here, including what algebra you know.  With respect to your comment -- the issue isn't whether the field has infinite cardinality... it is whether the field has positive characteristic.  Now consider the set $S:=\big\{I, J-I\big\}$ where $J$ is the ones matrix; what are the ranks over $\mathbb Q, \mathbb F_2,\mathbb F_3$ when $n\in \big\{2,3\big\}$.  (Hint: it refutes your indented quote conjecture).  I'd encourage you to work through this and type it up.